# Geoserver Layer Preview downloads a WMS file instead of showing preview in OpenLayers - Running Geoserver 2.21

Tags: geoserver

Using Kubernetes with the repository: docker.io/kartoza/geoserver.
Geoserver 2.21

Layer Previews not working for a majority for layer previews - I get a downloaded WMS file and a java.lang.NullPointerException  error

I have been trying to view layer previews which should have given me a preview of a layer but instead I get a blank page and a downloaded was file containing the following:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><!DOCTYPE ServiceExceptionReport SYSTEM "https://geoserver.staging.rcdo.co.uk/geoserver/schemas/wms/1.1.1/WMS_exception_1_1_1.dtd"> <ServiceExceptionReport version="1.1.1" >   <ServiceException>
      java.lang.NullPointerException
</ServiceException></ServiceExceptionReport>
```

Comment: Look in the log file to see the error

Comment: This is an excerpt from the geoserver log file when attempting the layer preview: 16:19DEBUG[security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request :'Path: /web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.demo.mappreviewpage, QueryString: 7&filter=false'; against '/web/**'
16:19DEBUG[security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher]-Matched Path: /web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.demo.mappreviewpage, QueryString:7&filter=false with /web/**
16:19:39 TRACE[geoserver.monitor] - Testing /web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.demo.MapPreviewPage for monitor filtering

Comment: Look for a line starting caused by

Comment: Found nothing in the geoserver log file but this in the Catalina log file: org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [org.postgresql.shaded.com.ongres.scram.client.ScramClient$1]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access. - This suggests that it could be a problem trying to connect to the database ?